# Subtracting a value from first row and the result to be subtracted further from the next row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with  fields (id,amount,points). Sample values are

```
id  amount points 
1   4000     450
2   3000     250
3   4000     400
```

Now I want to subtract "600" from the points column of the first row and the remaining 150 balance to be subtracted from the 2nd row and so on. So if the subtraction at any point of stage gives me 0 , stop performing further subtractions and update all the rows used for subtraction. In this case then the final table after subtracting 600 will look like.

```
id  amount points 
1   4000     0
2   3000     100
3   4000     400
```

How could it be done. I am using mysql and PHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I am a beginner and I have tried to implement this logic by writing simple queries first and did not find any success atleast. Since this is the first time I have such a logic requirement

Comment: @Saurabh Kedia, you expect to solve this only with query? Or with help of php script?

Comment: query would be better..but if PHP is a possible way then why not

Comment: i was just now trying to figure out this using php array but still in progress of the logic

Comment: Hope this helps. I personally don't like my solution http://www.phpwin.org/s/fTBRxp

Comment: The simplest way is with a variable

Comment: thanks. the logic that you have written worked for me :D

Comment: just for my knowledge, could it be also done by sql queries?